# iPhone 6 Wifi AC Speed

Tags: iphone

I wish to get a 802.11ac wifi router that will get the most out of my iPhone 6. I have looked but can't find any specifications that say which would be the best match. Routers all seem to have an AC rating AC1750, AC3200 for example which I understand is total Mb speed for both 2.4G and 5Ghz. Where in the iPhone 6 specifications does it say what the speed is so I can find an equally capable AC router?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.apple.com/iphone-6/specs/, the iPhone 6 supports 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wi‑Fi. So any router supporting the same standards should (and usually will) match your phone.

For potential speeds, see

- http://www.macrumors.com/2014/10/01/iphone-6-wifi-compared-to-iphone-5s/
- http://www.iclarified.com/44330/iphone-wifi-speed-test-80211ac-iphone-6-plus-vs-80211n-iphone-5s-video
- http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/09/iphone-6-plus-vs-iphone-6-vs-iphone-5s-speed-test.html

but keep in mind that maximal throughput depends on a lot of factors like packet/file size, router model, interference, distance between device and router etc.

Comment: Do you know the speed in mb/s? (See OP)

Comment: The speed is defined by the respective standards :-) Given somewhat modern equipment, the variance across different router models may be small than real-world influences like interference etc.

Comment: Thank you Cousin, iPhone Mb/s capability to match router capability is the question.

Comment: For example, an AC1750 router capability is 1300 Mb/s on 5Ghz. Can the iPhone 6 go that fast or is it something lower like 867 or 433 Mb/s?